# Circumscribed and Inscribed Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

If we circumscribe a triangle about a circle and then using the points of the tangency we inscribe a triangle in the circle, does these two triangles have to be similar?
I think that their length sides doesn't have to be proportional but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You should be able to draw some pictures where the triangles are clearly not similar (think angles rather than lengths).

Answer (score 0):

The smaller one is called the intouch or contact triangle of the larger triangle. According to [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContactTriangle.html),
$$a'=(-a+b+c)\cos \frac{A}{2}.$$
It should be easy to find a counterexample to similarity from that.